# Trusty Tahr & RDP

Tags: 14.04, rdp

I'm looking for a way to RDP into 14.04 using the Unity desktop environment.

I've successfully been able to RDP into 14.04 using the MATE, and XFCE desktop environment, but to be honest I don't care much for either. I've become accustomed to the Unity interface so I'd like to stick with it.

I've tried to load the Unity 2D environment using Synaptic, but I don't have the option to select a 2D desktop during login, which is what is required for unity to work (if the option is not available on login, it won't be available for RDP)....at least that's what worked for me when running Precise.

Any suggestions?

System: ASUS CM 6870, i7, 64 Bit Architecture, 16 GB DDR3, 4 TB HD

Comment: What do your system specs have to do with this question?

Comment: I'm a green-behind-the-ear noobie (first post on any website EVER). I'm not knowledgeable enough to know what's important, so I included it. Sorry, didn't mean to clog up the information stream!